# Autofac instance scopes

Tags: c#, .net, ioc-container, autofac

I am using Autofac IoC.
My question is: If  I use extension for registration InstancePerLifetimeScope(), will it disposed after scope is ended?
And if it true, how to know where it will end?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You could use logging to show it being disposed.

[This article explains all about autofac lifetime](http://nblumhardt.com/2011/01/an-autofac-lifetime-primer/)

[Check out the Autofac OnRelease event](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/LifetimeEvents)